# Ubuntu 14.04 - icedtea-6-plugin:i386 : Depends: icedtea-netx:i386 (= 1.5-1ubuntu1)

Tags: java, software-installation, icedtea

First of all, I'm a noob on ubuntu.
I needed to run a Java application and installed latest version.
After that, tried to run .jar file, it worked, but when I try to run the installed files, they give me an error sayin' that the application is 32bits and my java (and ubuntu) installation is 64bits.
After googling a while, found that I needed to install icedtea. Tried to do so, but couldn't succeed.

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Gives me

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
icedtea-6-plugin:i386 : Depends: icedtea-netx:i386 (= 1.5-1ubuntu1) but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

Then tried

```
sudo apt-get -f autoremove
```

And returns me

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  icedtea-netx:i386
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  icedtea-netx:i386
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 55 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 19,5 kB of archives.
After this operation, 155 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http:// ec. archive. ubuntu. com/ ubuntu/ trusty/main icedtea-netx i386 1.5-1ubuntu1 [19,5 kB]
Fetched 19,5 kB in 15s (1.231 B/s)         
(Reading database ... 187313 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../icedtea-netx_1.5-1ubuntu1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking icedtea-netx:i386 (1.5-1ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/icedtea-netx_1.5-1ubuntu1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite shared '/usr/bin/policyeditor', which is different from other instances of package icedtea-netx:i386
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/icedtea-netx_1.5-1ubuntu1_i386.deb
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ trusty/partner amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive. canonical. com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_partner_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http:// archive. canonical. com /ubuntu/ trusty/partner i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive. canonical .com_ ubuntu_dists_trusty_partner_binary-i386_Packages)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

(Added some spaces to links since I couldn't post it exactly like I copied it from terminal)

Tried

```
sudo apt-get update
```

And still same issue.

Any ideas on how to remove this package and it's dependencies via console? Or if it's not possible, how to remove them mannualy?

Thanks in advance!
Pablo

Comment: The application error makes no sense. Java bytecode is designed to run on any OS and architecture the JVM supports. Assuming it is in Java, I would consider the application to be poorly written if it expects to run only on 32-bit Java.

Comment: On the more important note here, you can't install both `icedtea-netx` (which you presumably already have installed) and `icedtea-netx:i386`, since both packages install different binary files in the same location (`/usr/bin/policyeditor`). These packages, unlike most library packages, aren't multiarch (since it's assumed you'll want applications that are for your architecture), and so can't be installed simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

try this

> sudo -i
>
> ```
> dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/icedtea-netx_1.5-1ubuntu1_i386.deb
>
> apt-get autoremove
>
> apt-get update
>
> apt-get upgrade
> ```

Comment: I ran into a similar problem to the one described by the OP. Running `dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/icedtea-netx_1.5-1ubuntu1_i386.deb` with the correct package path (given in the error message) solved the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It clearly says that "sudo apt-get -f install" without giving anything after that.
That'll automatically clear the unwanted packages and you'll be good to go.
Trust me it worked for me.

Comment: Already tried, but didn't work.

Comment: Still the same problem